# Что не так с intent-filter в моем манифесте?

Tags: android

Сделал intent-filter в манифесте приложения, чтобы в webview открывать ссылки моего сайта. Вот кусок кода

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
      android:host="*.xn--.xn--p1ai"
      android:scheme="http" />
    <data
      android:host="*.xn--.xn--p1ai"
      android:scheme="https" />
    <data
      android:host="*.сайт.рф"
      android:scheme="http" />
    <data
      android:host="*.сайт.рф"
      android:scheme="https" />
```

При нажатии на ссылку поддомен.сайт.рф всплывает список приложений с моим, и вроде все работает, но если ссылка будет поддомен.сайт.рф/категория/материал, то материал не открывается и вместо него открыватся стартовая страница, т.е. поддомен.сайт.рф.
Может это изза того, что начальная html страница внутри приложения? Как это исправить? Гугл ничего понятного для меня не выдает

P.S. ссылки в интент фильтре намеренно изменены

Comment: Покажите код открытия кликнутой ссылки в WebView.

Comment: спасибо, я разобрался. была опечатка